# How can I get the function bound to an onclick attribute?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've got a function bound to the `onclick` event in the html, like so:

```
<script>
    function f1(){ alert('hello world'); };
</script>

<a onclick="f1()">test</a>
```

I'd like to do something with that function, like bind it to another event. I tried this in jQuery:

```
var defaultFunction = $('a').attr('onclick');
```

but `defaultFunction` is defined as a string rather than the function itself. I can evaluate it with `eval(defaultFunction)`, but that makes me feel dirty. Is there a way I can access the function itself, rather than the string?

i.e. I'd like to be able to call `defaultFunction()` and do whatever the default onclick behavior bound to the `a` element is. (In this case, call `f1()`).

[Here's a fiddle that tries to do that, but fails.](http://jsfiddle.net/o8b5j15k/1/)

Comment: I think the real question is, why are you doing this, and what are you really trying to achieve? :)

Comment: Mostly I'm trying to satisfy my own curiosity. I was answering a different question and wasn't sure how to go about getting the function bound to an `onclick` attribute, so I figured I'd ask.

Comment: You may want to review the other answers as the one you have currently selected is not the correct answer.

Comment: It's the only one that actually answers my question. The rest tell me how I should be binding functions differently.

Comment: onclick() in html will soon no longer work and is considered bad. Your code will break as browsers update. binding is the way it will be for now on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's just `onclick` attribute, no jQuery required:

```
<script>
    function f1(){ alert('hello world'); };
</script>

<a onclick="f1()" id="aa">test</a>
<a id="bb">test2</a>

<script>
    bb.onclick = aa.onclick;
    // or
    bb.onclick = function (){ alert('hello bb'); };   
</script>
```

Comment: Just a warning for anyone considering using this code: accessing DOM elements by id directly as variables (like `aa` and `bb` here) is considered bad form and might not work everywhere. Read more http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1097250

Comment: @xec Yes, it's just a shortcut for brevity here.

Comment: This is a honorable way to do click events and should not be used. Inline event handlers are frowned upon. We are not in html2 any more we are in html5 and inline event handlers should be removed.

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon original poster, that is the author of the question.

Comment: How can i send a notice to the OP?

Comment: @PatrickW.McMahon I mean, your should have posted your original comment not to my answer but rather to OP's question.

Answer (score 2):

see this `document.getElementById("id_of_your_element").onclick` if that help you, it will return `click` handler, and you can call that, but its not right to raise events manually

Answer (score 2):

Something like this:

[Example](http://jsfiddle.net/yLr7s2b1/7/)

```
var defaultFunction = $('a').attr('onclick');
var defaultFunctionName = defaultFunction.substring(0, defaultFunction.indexOf('('));

$('div').on('click', function(){

   if(typeof window[defaultFunctionName] ==="function")
   {
         window[defaultFunctionName]();
   }
    alert('Hello universe!');
});
```

Comment: +1 for this - it's really a great way of saying "are you sure you want to do things this way?":)

Comment: :) Yeah. OP's questions is getting misinterpreted.

Comment: Just a note for people reading this and going "wut?": This code first gets the onclick attribute (as text) and then extracts the **name** of the function, then on click checks to see if that function exists in the global namespace (`window`) before calling it. Both brilliant and silly at the same time!

Comment: +1 for above comment. The question is pure R&D type and above code shows one way to call a function (if it exists in default window namespace) based name of the function.

Comment: But why? The string has already been parsed and made into a nice shiny function object. Why not just use that function?

Comment: @cookiemonster I'm not quite sure what you're talking about, the two variables `defaultFunction` and `defaultFunctionName` are both strings.

Comment: @xec: I mean getting the string using `.attr()`, and then parsing it out to figure out the function name. It would seem to be cleaner and safer to just grab the function object that the browser created when the page loaded and invoke that, which will invoke the `f1` function.

Comment: Why do all that when plain old javascript can do this in one line.

Answer (score 1):

Use this:

```
function f1() { 
    alert('hello world');
};
$('a').on('click', f1);
```

Here is your fiddle with the fix: http://jsfiddle.net/o8b5j15k/2/

Comment: In my case, `f1` has already been defined, and is bound to the `a` element. I'm trying to figure out what's been bound to the `a` element so I can do something like bind it to another node. If I knew that it was `f1`, I'd just bind that directly, but I don't know that.

Comment: if you want to have multiple events on an element and or if you want to make your life easy and simple and all your code manageable. Then use addEventListener()

Answer (score 1):

Instead of attempting to copy the function bound inline, you could trigger the click event programatically:

```
function defaultFunction() {
    $("a[onclick]").click(); // change selector to match your actual element
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/o8b5j15k/3/

Answer (score 1):

Its best to use **addEventListener()** you can add all types of events. example: "click", "mousemove", "mouseover", "mouseout", "resize" and many more. the false at the end is to stop the event from traversing up the dom. If you want parent dom objects to also receive the event just change it to true. also this example requires no javascript libraries. This is just plain old javascript and will work in every browser with nothing extra needed.

Also **addEventListener() is better than onClick()** as you can add an unlimited number of event listeners to a dom element. If you have an onClick() on an element and then set another onClick() on the same element you have overwritten the first onClick(). Using addEventListener() if i want multiple click events to trigger when i click on an element i can do it with no problem.

If you want data about the element that is triggering the event you can pass the event to the function. You will see in my example function(e) e is the event and you can use **e** or **this** to target the element that is being triggered. Using e or this i can also get more data about the triggered event. for example if the event was a mousemove or mouseclick i can get the x and y position of the mouse at the time of the event.

```
   <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <title>exampe</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <a id="test" href="">test</a>
    <script>
        document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",function(e){
            alert('hello world');
            alert('my element '+e);
            alert('my element '+this);
        },false);
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

if you want to have addEventListener call a function just change the 2nd value to the function name like this.

```
document.getElementById("test").addEventListener("click",f1,false);
```

this will execute the function

```
function f1(){ ... }
```

When you want to remove an event listener just call target.**removeEventListener**(type, listener[, useCapture]). Very simple and easy to manage.

Comment: What makes you think you can come walking in here, posting decent, working and proper code and do things the right way? We were having a great time posting horrible horrible code and you make us all look bad! (Er... I mean Welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Comment: This answer should be selected as the best answer.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60102/discussion-between-xec-and-patrick-w-mcmahon).

Comment: The problem of plain `addEventListener` is that you don't know in runtime what listeners you have, which is needed by OP.

Comment: simple trouble shooting can tell a person what event listeners are connected to an item. also the browser gives you tools to check all the events connected to an element. You can also watch events trigger in the browser using the built in tools.